# Weird problem with lists and resource file in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

i'm encountering a weird problem. On the project i'm working on we have some lists, the titles and descriptions of each field of each list are stored in a resource file which is deployed in the hive by feature, like the lists ...
First all labels were in French, then we integrated the translation made by the client within the resource file ... nothing really complicated, just copy/paste ... but when i checked if anything was wrong, i noticed that some labels were still in French !!
So i checked again in the resource file if those labels were still in French or not ... they were in English. I even purged the resource file ... all labels were like "$Resources:myresource, mylabel" except ... those who were still in French !!!
i reset iis but still i can't figure out where the problem comes from ...

Has anyone encountered the same problem ?

Thank you very very much !!

Answer (score 1):

It could be caching problem. I had the same problem when deployed custom webpart page with alluserswebpart on it using feature. After a while, I changed resource value of one webpart property. And nothing happened. I tried reset IIS, redeploy feature, restart SharePoint services. With no luck!

Problem was solved for me only after I reboot the server.

You can also try clear the SharePoint Configuration Cache, it may help. Please, follow this link for details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx

Be careful, delete only the XML files, as it is described in the article!

Comment: I did reboot the server, i followed the steps in the article, but still i have the same problem ...

Comment: did you redeploy the solution after reboot? try redeploying it and making iisreset